# Resharper and other settings shared between workstations

Tags: settings, resharper, share

How do i share resharper settings and other between workstations like home and work?
is there an easy solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have ReSharper 6.1 or above, you can share the settings file using Dropbox, Google drive, etc. 
Read [this post](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/12/resharper61-settings-dropbox-and-company-wide/) to learn more.

Answer (score -1):

i have a solution on sharing resharper between workstations (home,work,laptop).

all relevant files are located on : C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\ReSharper or even C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\

using a tool named "junction link magic" i create a junction on this folder that points to a folder in my skydrive synced folder (or dropbox).

every workstation that has skydrive has only to point to this path as described below. this way everything in that folder gets synced (plugins!!!!)

This actualy work for many thinks like: Visual Studio, Sql management studio, and other tools...